# Problema con la libreria SweetAlert2 haciendo validaciones

Tags: django, sweetalert2

Buen@s amigos!
Estoy haciendo validaciones utilizando la libreria SweetAlert2, cuando voy a insertar un registro y uno de sus datos ya se encuentra en la BD entonces me salta la alerta utilizando SweetAlert2, donde me dice cual es el dato que ya se encuentra insertado, todo perfecto hasta aca.

El problema viene dado cuando intento que haga lo mismo para cuando utilizo `unique_together` entre dos campos, pues debo verificar que no se vuelva a insertar en la BD el mismo `id_tipoocupacion` en un `mes`. El SweetAlert2 me muestra la alerta y no se inserta, pero no me dice cuales fueron los campos que ya han sido insertados en la BD y necesito que me muestre esta información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código donde se llama al SweetAlert2:

```
 <script>
        {% if form.errors %}
            var errors = '';
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    errors += '{{error}}\n';
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: errors,
                icon: 'error'
            });
        {% endif %}
    </script>
```

Sin embargo, si en el template dentro del `form` pongo el código `{{ form.errors }}` si me muestra el mensaje perfectamente.

Verificando varias cosas me he dado cuenta de que el SweetAlert2 siempre me muestra los campos que en el `modelo` tienen la propiedad `unique=True`, en este caso los campos `id_tipoocupacion` y `mes` no lo tienen, lo que tienen es el `unique_together` para que estos dos no se repitan en la BD.

Alguien me puede ayudar a resolver este problema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haciendo una revision logre encontrar que mi problema se encuentra en el código del `script`.Para mostrar el error de `unique_together` en el SweetAlert2, debo acceder a los errores de formulario generales en lugar de iterar sobre los campos individuales. Al usar `form.non_field_errors` para obtener los errores que no están asociados a campos específicos. Por lo cual modifique el código para el caso de que acceder a `form.non_field_errors`o a `field.errors`:

```
    <script>
        {% if form.errors %}
            {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                var errors = '';
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    errors += '{{ error }}\n';
                {% endfor %}
                swal.fire({
                    title: 'Error!',
                    text: errors,
                    icon: 'error'
                });
            {% else %}
                var errors = '';
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            errors += '{{error}}\n';
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    swal.fire({
                    title: 'Error!',
                    text: errors,
                    icon: 'error'
                });
            {% endif %}    
        {% endif %}
    </script>
```